# MongoDB pipeline Query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to build a MongoDB pipeline query but I can't get it to work. The modified query is below.

```
pipeline = [
    {match: {
      objectId: JSON.stringify({$eq : 'params.id'}),
      isDeleted: {$ne : true}
    }},
    ....,
]
console.log(pipeline)
```

When I print this query I get the results below

```
[ { match: { objectId: '{"$eq":"params.id"}', isDeleted: [Object] } } ]
```

which fails to execute. The are two problems, the first is `JSON.stringify` quotes the entire condition in a single quote after `objectId`. The second problem is without `JSON.stringify` my conditions are treated as an `[Object]` as in `isDeleted`.

What I am expecting is

```
[ { match: { objectId: {$eq:"params.id"}, isDeleted: {$ne : true} } } ]
```

You can reproduce this by saving the sample code in `.js` file and executing it using `node file.js`

Comment: Don't use `JSON.stringify` and provide a data example if it is possible.

Comment: What does "_my conditions are treated as an `[Object]`_" mean? Are you referring to when it is being _printed_ (to the console)? If so that's just an output formatting thing and has nothing to do with the actual query being executed. Are you doing this inside of the `mongosh` utility?

Comment: you should treat it just like how you did with isDeleted. if you want to print the query you could just `console.log(JSON.stringify(pipeline))` but inside the query itself do not stringify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply?

```
pipeline = [
    {match: {
      objectId: params.id,
      isDeleted: {$ne : true}
    }},
    ....,
]
```

I assume you are concerned about [NoSQL-Injection](https://blog.websecurify.com/2014/08/hacking-nodejs-and-mongodb.html). Have a look at [mongo-sanitize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-sanitize)

```
var sanitize = require('mongo-sanitize');
pipeline = [
    {match: {
      objectId: sanitize(params.id),
      isDeleted: {$ne : true}
    }},
    ....,
]
```

or use

```
pipeline = [
    {match: {
      objectId: JSON.stringify(params.id),
      isDeleted: {$ne : true}
    }},
    ....,
]
```